# Is it possible to use chef-client in local mode with external repository as a source for cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra

Is it possible to use chef-client in local mode without downloading cookbooks to the node but instead specifying e.g. cookbooks repository URI?

I'm wondering if it would be possible to store my cookbooks e.g. on github and use them with local mode.

Comment: This sounds like defeating the point of chef-solo, which is being able to run isolated from a local tarball (remote is supported also, but the main idea of being serverless is the ability to be isolated).

Comment: I just wanted to save myself the need to write script that will download the cookbook. I know that I could(maybe should) use Chef Server here, but I just don't want to have another piece that I need to manage, I only have few simple machines and chef server looks like an overkill here.

Comment: The recipe-url parameter accept http urls of a tarball, berks package sounds like the way to go to build the package,  with some kind of upload just after, then chef-zero/solo will download thus tarball from a central point for you without a wrapper (just command line arguments)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a feature of Chef. A more common approach is to use `berks vendor` or `chef export` in a script on the node to download the required cookbooks and then involve `chef-solo` after that. You can wrap that whole process in a script to simplify it or look at management tools that already do so like `knife-solo`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll look into tools that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the Berkshelf tool that is included in the [ChefDK](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/)

## Example

Create a file called "Berksfile" with the following content:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook 'java'
```

This example downloads the "java" cookbook and its dependencies from the [Chef supermarket](http://berkshelf.com/). If you check the doco there is also support for git repositories, github and even Chef servers,

To install Java run the following commands:

```
berks vendor cookbooks
sudo chef-client -z -o java
```

Comment: Sounds cool, but I still need to create some kind of wrapper cookbook and somehow download it to the node, right ?

Comment: @Progress1ve Nope. Create a file called "Berksfile" (as above) and run the two commands. It'll run the default recipe of the community "java" cookbook to install Java. The "java" cookbook and all it's dependencies get downloaded by berkshelf to a local "cookbooks" directory for chef client to use in local mode (-z). The Berkshelf file syntax supports the use of a local wrapper cookbook or just download the cookbooks from a remote site. Try it out.